# schedule update issue

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, schedule

This might sound pretty straightforward. I've created a method and I've called it as below in the init method.

```
[self createNewSpr:ccp(s.width * 0.25,s.height-200)];
[self createNewSpr:ccp(s.width * 0.50,s.height-200)];
[self createNewSpr:ccp(s.width * 0.75,s.height-200)];
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

I've defined a for loop in my update method that imposes a gravity higher than that of the world on the sprites. Only the last call is affected by the new gravity but the first and second act on the world gravity. I am not sure what is wrong but I suspect it to be the scheduleUpdate. Please Help.

Edit: Update Method :

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt 
{
 int32 velocityIterations = 8;
 int32 positionIterations = 1; 
 world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
 for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
   {
     if (b == sprite)
        {
         b->ApplyForce( b2Vec2(0.0,20*b->GetMass()),b->GetWorldCenter());
        }
   }
}

the createNewSpr:
-(void) createNewSpr:(CGPoint)pos {
//CGSize s = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
b2Vec2 startPos = [self toMeters:pos];
CGFloat linkHeight = 0.24;
CGFloat linkWidth = 0.1;

b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position = startPos;
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.density = 0.1;
b2PolygonShape polygonShape;
polygonShape.SetAsBox(linkWidth,linkHeight);
fixtureDef.shape = &polygonShape;


//first
b2Body* link = world->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
link->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );

PhysicsSprite* segmentSprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"sg.png"];
[self addChild:segmentSprite];
[segmentSprite setPhysicsBody:link];


b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set( 0,  linkHeight);
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set( 0, -linkHeight);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    b2Body* newLink = world->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
    newLink->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );
    PhysicsSprite* segmentSprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"sg.png"];
    [self addChild:segmentSprite];
    [segmentSprite setPhysicsBody:link];

    revoluteJointDef.bodyA = link;
    revoluteJointDef.bodyB = newLink;
    world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );

    link = newLink;//next iteration
}

PhysicsSprite* circleBodySprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"cb.png"];
[self addChild:circleBodySprite z:1];

b2CircleShape circleShape;
circleShape.m_radius = circleBodySprite.contentSize.width/2 / PTM_RATIO;
fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
b2Body* chainBase =world->CreateBody( &bodyDef );
chainBase->CreateFixture( &fixtureDef );
[circleBodySprite setPhysicsBody:chainBase];
sprite = chainBase;

revoluteJointDef.bodyA = link;
revoluteJointDef.bodyB = chainBase;


revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set(0,linkWidth);

revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0,linkWidth);
world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );
}
```

Comment: @xlc0212: the update method is:                              `-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
    int32 velocityIterations = 8;
    int32 positionIterations = 1;
    world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations); 
    
    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {
      if (b == sprite) {
        b->ApplyForce( b2Vec2(0.0,20*b->GetMass()),b->GetWorldCenter());
        }
    }//body with circle fixture
}`

Comment: you should edit your question with properly formatted code rather than providing it as a jumbled paste in a comment

Comment: sorry about my formatting, i didn't know about the five minute limit for editing comments.

Comment: you should edit the question (not the comment) as per Andrew's suggestion. Please add in the question your code for createNewSpr

Comment: Now write your createNewSpr method code..

Comment: Check my answer.... You will come to know the problem.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `createNewSpr` method...

You have assigned `sprite` to a body... So When you call this method three times, `sprite` refers to 3rd object only..

When you compare in `update` method, it just puts gravity on 3rd object...

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: this makes all bodies respond to the imposed gravity and the sprites are behaving strangely. How can I restrict it to certain bodies?

Comment: for that I think in your class PhysicsSprite you need to keep tag or variable for bodies you want to put gravity in.. Or keep sprites in arrays.. Thats your logic How you do that... It may differ from person to person... I know these two ways.. Best way is to keep those affected objects in an array and then use that array here, :)